# Size Two Elements so they Align at the Bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup with the following layout:

[image]

It would be nice if I could make the large box on the right taller so that the two large boxes are aligned at the bottom.

I can do this on my computer by setting the height of the box on the right so that the bottoms line up. However, there is some text and other elements that determine the position of the box on the left. This could cause the position to change on different computers (with different browsers, fonts, zoom, etc.). And so the bottoms might not line up on another user's computer.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to set the height of the large box on the right such that the two boxes will *always* line up at the bottom?

*Note: Solutions involving HTML, CSS, or JavaScript would all be appreciated.*

**EDIT:**

Added [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkm3x0u9/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="PopUp">

    <div id="LeftPanel">
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <hr>
        <p>Some More Text</p>
        <div id="LeftBox">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="RightPanel">
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <div id="RightBox">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#PopUp {
    width: 750px;
    height: 350px;
}
div#LeftPanel {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
div#RightPanel {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
div#LeftBox {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height: 150px;
}
div#RightBox {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanWood `flexbox` is a CSS solution, but as Paulie_D pointed out, it's IE10+. http://flexboxin5.com/

Comment: @JonathanWood Did any of the answers work for you? Please, don't forget to accept one.

Comment: @JonathanWood sorry didn't mean to be harrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`flexbox` version**

```css
div#PopUp {
  width: 750px;
  padding:1em;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div#LeftPanel {
  flex:0 0 300px;

 display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div#LeftBox {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  flex:1;
}

div#RightPanel {
  flex:0 0 300px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div#RightBox {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="PopUp">

  <div id="LeftPanel">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <p>Some More Text</p>
    <div id="LeftBox">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quisquam beatae cumque vel, maxime quaerat, placeat laboriosam ducimus tempora consequuntur sequi, quod neque. Commodi, nulla.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="RightPanel">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <div id="RightBox">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos impedit, nesciunt placeat, quasi alias repudiandae obcaecati repellendus maiores, distinctio dicta, soluta voluptatibus laboriosam deleniti dolores eum! Blanditiis hic dolore in placeat architecto exercitationem, voluptatem sed consequuntur soluta corporis repellat enim, eius sint. Minus dolorem eveniet quia enim officia necessitatibus. Id blanditiis velit nesciunt culpa nihil veniam, possimus, provident quisquam a, illo veritatis maxime minus corporis temporibus in tempore mollitia quia cumque dolorum inventore optio officia, consequuntur quas. Labore accusamus consectetur ullam sit error, aspernatur nihil nostrum, temporibus veniam deleniti minima ipsum. Repudiandae, nemo maxime consectetur! Debitis mollitia nostrum laborum, quia.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LVmrqj?editors=110)

Note: I used height `auto` but if a fixed height is required, this can be accommodated with the appropriate `overflow`.

[**Browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

[**CSS-Tricks: Guide to Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
A simple JavaScript solution:
1. On the left side, put both Office & Destinations, in a parent div element.
2. Get the height of this new left parent div element.
3. Set this height to the right text box.

```
divRight.style.height = divLeft.clientHeight + 'px';
```

4. Since they are of same size, you would have bottoms aligned

Sample example JSFiddle is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/hcx2wepd/1/

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems a lot different to me. In your example, you have two divs that are the same height and are aligned at the top. I'm not sure how that would be applied to the jsFiddle I posted.